# Biblatex, multi lingual references and backref

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing, backref

With help of `langid` field in `.bib` entries, the `biblatex` package can format each bibliographic reference in its own language.

If I add `backref=true` into the `biblatex` options, I have back references at the ending of each reference.

But each back reference uses the language of the reference instead of the current language.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[paper=a5paper,hmargin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,american]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dupont-2018,
  author =   {Dupont, Jean and Dupond, Pierre},
  title =    {Ce livre: un livre en français},
  year =     2018,
  langid =   {french}
}
@book{doe-2017,
  Author =   {Doe, John and Doe, Jerry},
  title =    {This book: an american book},
  Year =     2017,
  langid =   {american}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
bibencoding=auto,
backend=biber,
backref=true,
language=auto,
autolang=other,
style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\section{American/Américain section}
Some citations: \cite{dupont-2018,doe-2017}.

\printbibliographybibliographic

\newpage

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}

  \section{Section en Français}
  Quelques citations: \cite{dupont-2018,doe-2017}.

  \printbibliography
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

## First page

> [image]

The first page is in american. The french book title ("*ce livre : un livre en français*") is composed in french (with a space before ":"). The american book title ("*This book: an american book*") is composed  in american (no space before ":").

But all back references should be in american, as "(cit. on pp. ??)".

## Second page

> [image]

The second page is in french. The french book title ("*ce livre : un livre en français*") is composed in french (with a space before ":"). The american book title ("*This book: an american book*") is composed  in american (no space before ":").

But all back references should be in french, as "(cf. p. ??)".

## My Question

How to specify that back reference in a bibliographic reference must use the current language (instead of the language of the bibliographic reference)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try and remember the language active at the beginning of the bibliography and restore that for printing the back references.

The command `\biblang` is defined analogous to `\mainlang` and can be used to typeset text in the language surrounding the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french,american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  language=auto, autolang=other,
  backref=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\blx@biblangname}{\bbl@main@language}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \edef\blx@biblangname{\languagename}%
}

\newcommand*{\biblang}{%
  \select@language{\blx@biblangname}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{parens:biblang}{%
  \mkbibparens{\biblang{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens:biblang]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dupont-2018,
  author = {Dupont, Jean and Dupond, Pierre},
  title  = {Ce livre: un livre en français},
  year   = 2018,
  langid = {french},
}
@book{doe-2017,
  author = {Doe, John and Doe, Jerry},
  title  = {This book: an american book},
  year   = 2017,
  langid = {american}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{American/Américain section}
Some citations: \cite{dupont-2018,doe-2017}.

\printbibliography

\newpage

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
  \section{Section en Français}
  Quelques citations: \cite{dupont-2018,doe-2017}.

  \printbibliography
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image: cit. on pp. 1, 2]

[image: cf. p. 1, 2]

Comment: Perfect patch. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible kludge, but it does work. Provided you only have American and French sections, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[paper=a5paper,hmargin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,american]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dupont-2018,
  author =   {Dupont, Jean and Dupond, Pierre},
  title =    {Ce livre: un livre en français},
  year =     2018,
  langid =   {french}
}
@book{doe-2017,
  Author =   {Doe, John and Doe, Jerry},
  title =    {This book: an american book},
  Year =     2017,
  langid =   {american}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
bibencoding=auto,
backend=biber,
backref=true,
language=auto,
autolang=other,
style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newif\iffrenchsec
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\iffrenchsec
            cf\adddotspace p\adddot
          \else
            cit\adddotspace on pp\adddot
          \fi
          \ppspace}
         {\iffrenchsec
            cf\adddotspace p\adddot
          \else
            cit\adddotspace on p\adddot
          \fi
          \ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\begin{document}

\section{American/Américain section}
Some citations: \cite{dupont-2018,doe-2017}.

\printbibliography

\newpage

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\frenchsectrue

  \section{Section en Français}
  Quelques citations: \cite{dupont-2018,doe-2017}.

  \printbibliography
\frenchsecfalse
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your _horrible kludge_ works... but it is not automatically applied.